# Function will not loop

Tags: python, function, loops

Have to make a table that runs functions. I can run the functions once, but after being able to submit for another function the code ends.

```
def main():
    menu()
    option=int(input('What option do you choose? '))
    if option==1:
        rol()
    if option==2:
        bing()
    if option==3:
        return 
    else:
        print('Please pick from the menu!')
        menu()
        option=int(input('What option do you choose? '))

How do I loop it so that after it goes through the options roll() and bingo(), and the menu is shown again, it actually goes through with the functions?
```

Comment: It doesn't appear your shown code as any loops at all, so what did you try?

Comment: Even with the edits, only `roll` contains a `while` block, not the main function, so still unclear what you tried there. Also, I don't think the other functions are really needed as part of a [mcve] that asks how to loop the main method itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code so that it will loop forever:

```
def main():
    while True:
        print('Please pick an option from the menu!')
        menu()

        option = int(input('What option do you choose? '))

        if option == 3:
            return
            
        if option == 1:
            roll()

        elif option == 2:
            bingo()
```

Comment: I assume `menu()` is the same as the print function, or that should be moved up

Comment: I don't know what menu is I just looped it so it will run forever, but i get what u mean by moving it up and how it will affect the coed :)

Comment: this worked! thanks! It won't let me accept the answer right now though..

Comment: np, I am glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main function works the way it is just once, you can simpy run the loop externally

```
def main():
  # your code ... 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  while True:
    main()
```